BLE is not advertising on nRF52840 dongle; how can I configure this dongle using coding?
I am working on nrf52840 in which the BLE is not Advertising even after I am adding one parameter. I just want to add the parameters at the time of adding the 2 parameters. As you can see in picture

At the time of adding the advertisement parameter I want to add 3 parameters

Namely Mac Address, Repeat advertising & repeat Interval and after adding this 3 parameter the advertisement is not working and I am unable to configure this parameters.
We don't use nrf Connect Sdk, we only use nrf52840 dongle.
How to configure this dongle using code?

I need to configure nRF52840 Dongle firmware. I would be interested to know the Method and firmware.
I need to add parameters in the firmware. I've already attempted it, but it's not working. What can I try next?


This is clearly a support request and has nothing to do with the software. Have you already requested help from Nordic Semiconductor?

Yes, I have explored various options but haven't found a suitable solution yet. Therefore, I'm continuing to explore different possibilities in search of the right solution.



I need to configure nRF52840 Dongle firmware. I would be interested to know the Method and firmware.


To add firmware to a microcontroller, you need to write some code to run, build the code and then generate hex/binary files. These files can be written to the chip using either a debugger or a bootloader.
There are usually several methods to do this, but if you have no strong opinions on the matter, it is usually a good idea to start with whatever the chip producer recommends.
Going to the webpage for the chip and looking for "getting started" often works.
For the nRF52840 dongle specifically, the current getting started guide recommended by Nordic Semiconductor ASA is https://academy.nordicsemi.com/.

We don't use nrf Connect Sdk, we only use nrf52840 dongle.

My above suggestion is for the nRF Connect SDK.
To change the code on the nRF52840Dongle you need to build code yourself. Nordic Semiconductor does not provide any GUI tools or similar to configure the chip. This means that you can not use only the nrf52840 dongle. You need some way to build and program your code.
Do you have any preferences in this regard?
If I can understand why you do not want to use the nRF Connect SDK, maybe I can come up with better suggestions.
